# inserting date value in sql server and retrieving it into textbox using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, c#-3.0

i am trying to insert date value from datetimepicker into sql server database  and retrieve it into a textbox using select command.i am using c# as frontend language.please fix this for me.
here is the code i have written.

```
 private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into xt1 values('" + textBox1.Text + "'," + int.Parse(textBox2.Text) + ")", cnn);
            cnn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("saved");
            cnn.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception x)
        { 
            MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
            cnn.Close();

        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }

    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        textBox1.Text = dateTimePicker1.Text;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            SqlCommand  ad = new SqlCommand ("select * from xt1 where id=" + int.Parse(textBox2.Text), cnn);
            SqlDataReader dr = ad.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            while (dr.HasRows)
            {
                textBox1.Text = dr[0].ToString();
                textBox2.Text = DateTime .Parse ( dr[1].ToString());
            }

            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
        }
```

insertion into database is successfull but retrieval is the nightmare to me..

Comment: Can you show what error / exception are you getting ?

Comment: First thing to do: stop putting values directly into your SQL like that. It's bad practice in various ways, most worryingly because you're vulnerable to [SQL Injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) but also because you're representing your date/time as text, when there's no need. Additionally, you haven't told us what's wrong with the code you've given us - "retrieval is the nightmare" is not a clear problem description. (You should probably just be casting to `DateTime`, but at least tell us what's wrong at the moment.)

Comment: Please discribe more closely what errors you are experiencing and where in your code they happen. We as a community are here to test your code, so please be more precise.

Comment: yeah i know that but its jus a windows form application..not to worry about any security attacks.and can you please tell me the good format to insert @jon skeet

Comment: Use parameterized SQL. *Always*, whether it's "just a Windows Forms application" or not. Then you don't need to worry about the format of the date/time at all.

Comment: @user1932583: Being a Windows Forms application doesn't automatically make it secure.  You should still use better database query practices.

Comment: actually i am not getting any errors but instead the application is not reacting any way..it is just not responding

Comment: ya ya i know @david and @@jon skeet..i am very new and i dont know exact format to insert .

Comment: @user1932583: When you step through this in a debugger, where/how does it fail?  On what line does the behavior begin to differ from what you expect?  What are the runtime values when this happens?

Comment: i am trying to retrieve data i have stored in the database using id ..i.e textbox2 value.but after entering id in textbox2 and clicking on view the application is neither responding nor giving any error.@David

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use concatenation to put data into SQL commands: use parameters.

   Otherwise you'll be subject to SQL Injection.
2. If your database column has a suitable type (eg. [`DateTime2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848733.aspx)) then there is no point converting to a string and back, it will come across as the right type:

   ```
   SqlDataReader dr = ad.ExecuteReader();
   dr.Read();
   while (dr.HasRows) {
     textBox2.Text = dr.GetDateTime(1).ToString(/* Pass suitable format and CultureInfo */);
     …
   }
   ```

***EDIT***

On re-reading your code I spotted this:

> ```
> private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     dateTimePicker1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
>     textBox1.Text = dateTimePicker1.Text;
> }
> ```

which appears to be resetting the `dateTimePicker1` every time its value changes. If I recall correctly setting the value will trigger the event: infinite loop. But also it does not seem to make sense: do you want to initialise on form load rather than on change?

Comment: ok i have given date as my data type in sql server and the date selected in datepicker control will go to textbox and then that text in the textbox will be saved to database.and now my problem is i am not getting the saved date into the textbox @richard

Comment: @user1932583 There is nothing in the code that is obvious. Have you tried debugging: set a break point at the start of `button2_Click`. First to ensure it is being called (you do set up the event handler?) and then what it is doing (eg. are you getting any records back?).

Comment: @user1932583: Getting what?

Comment: i am not gettin any records.

Comment: @user1932583 What happens if you run the same query (manually substitute the id) in SQL Server Management Studio (or other such tool): likely that you don't have the data you expect.

Comment: ya i just checked its coming.i can see the records using select * from table_name;

Comment: @user1932583 That is not what I asked. And [SO] is not the place for a introductory debugging tutorial: at least expand the question with the current state.

Comment: okay.i guess your not clear about my problem.i am developing an application that stores some data about a person.for that i have created two columns in a table ,dob as date and id as numeric.i am inserting values into database using ado.net with c# .while inserting i used a datepicekr and the value inserted in date picker will come in textbox and from textbox it will store into database.Insertion is successfull.next,i want to view the date into the textbox by entering the id.so,while debugging this i am neither getting any error nor the form is responding to any other actions(hung up).

Comment: @user1932583: see the edit to my question for the hang. Otherwise you need to work through under the debugger validating everything including those things you "know" are true (quite likely they're not ... and that leads to bug fixes.

Comment: i have tried your method and its giving me error like invalid cast.

Comment: @user1932583 This comment list is too long. Consider asking specific questions where you give the exact code and exact error that can be worked on. This is no place for "please debug my code".

Comment: i am not asking you to debug the error i got.i am jus asking to tell the way to isnert and retrieve date using c#.